# Border positioning: how to?

Tags: css, positioning, border, border-layout

I want to position the border, but this won't work. This is the CSS:

```
.menu-container {
    border-top: 5px solid #81806E;
    float: left;
    margin: 5px 27px 0 10px;
    width: 704px;
}
```

The problem is that this container, contains menu links. So if I adjust the width and margin, the border is coming with it. But I want to style it separately... How can I do this?

Comment: You should provide a testcase on http://jsfiddle.net and paste the link here, that way we can reproduce your problem and help you.

Comment: Question is not fully clear. Could you add your present HTML markup? And explain with that how you wanted to position the margin and how it comes now.

Comment: @Nelson, For only css and HTML, jsFiddle would be overkill. One can use http://dabblet.com/ for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the sample [design and code with result](http://tinkerbin.com/szSvcea2), is this you want?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="menu-container">
      <a class="menu-item" href="#">Menu 1</a>
      <a class="menu-item" href="#">Menu 2</a>
      <a class="menu-item" href="#">Menu 3</a>
      <a class="menu-item" href="#">Menu 4</a>
      <a class="menu-item" href="#">Menu 5</a>
    </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.menu-container {
    float: left;
    margin: 5px 27px 0 10px;
    width: 704px;
}
.menu-item{
  float:left;
  height:20px;
  margin-right:3px;
  border-top: 5px solid #81806E;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a p tag or span to list the menu items. You want to move the content with margin without moving border??.

You have to try by  placing the content of .menu-container inside some other tags by this way  your problem will be rectified.